# iPhone : Upload video to Youtube while running app in device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting following error while installing the application on my device. before running in device i am tested in simulator uploaded fine but in device i am getting this error :
plz help me how to solve this ..........

```
_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataYouTubeMediaGroup", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataUtilities", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaTitle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataServiceGoogleYouTube", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaKeywords", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_kGDataServiceDefaultUser", referenced from:
      -[YoutubeUploader uploadVideoFile] in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_kGDataSchemeYouTubeCategory", referenced from:
      -[YoutubeUploader uploadVideoFile] in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaDescription", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataEntryYouTubeUpload", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeUploader.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GDataMediaCategory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in YoutubeUploader.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the GData library but haven't linked/added it.
Check out [GData Objective-C Client Setup in XCode 4](http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/) on how to build/link the GData library correctly.

Comment: it's OK but i am running app in simulator is good in device it's crashing

Comment: Have you added the library to the Target dependencies ?